# Problem while updating shotwell

Tags: 14.04, shotwell

The last update of Shotwell is causing me troubles while updating my system. I tried with `sudo apt-get install -f` and I got this error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  shotwell
The following packages will be upgraded:
  shotwell
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/7,511 kB of archives.
After this operation, 25.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 299243 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../shotwell_0.18.1-1~trusty1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking shotwell (0.18.1-1~trusty1) over (0.18.0-0ubuntu4.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/shotwell_0.18.1-1~trusty1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/shotwell/icons/shotwell-16.svg', which is also in package shotwell-common 0.18.0-0ubuntu4.2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/shotwell_0.18.1-1~trusty1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Is there any chance of fixing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I submited question on Launchpad and got answer, so just in case someone else have similar problem here is how I solved it:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i /var/cache/apt/archives/shotwell_0.18.1-1~trusty1_i386.deb
```

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qt4-x11/+question/252665

Comment: This worked for me using the [Yorba ppa](https://launchpad.net/~yorba/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) on 64bit: `sudo dpkg --force-all -i /var/cache/apt/archives/shotwell_0.18.1-1~trusty1_amd64.deb`

Answer (score -1):

I have installed `shotwell_0.18.1` successfully, by running these commands:`

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge shotwell*
sudo apt-get install shotwell
```

Comment: Tried but not working, I get this dependency error: gnome : Depends: shotwell but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Still get the same error :-( `Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/shotwell_0.18.1-1~trusty1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`